# React Native, Type Error Requested keys of a value that is not a object

Tags: android, reactjs, debugging, native

I'm developing a crossplatform app with react native. Now I'm testing it on android device, on ios device is all ok. The problem is that when I execute my app I found this error:

Type Error Requested keys of a value that is not a object

And another interesting things is that this error occurs only in normale mode and not in debug mode.
The piece of code indicted is

```
render() {
 var { data, deviceName } = this.props
 const sectionListData = [];

 for(var i in data){
   sectionListData.push({key: data[i].istance, data: data[i].data});
   this.objectId = data[i].url
 }
 return (
   <SectionList
     sections={sectionListData}
     keyExtractor={item => item.id}
     renderSectionHeader={this._renderHeader}
     numColumns={5}
     renderItem={this._renderItem}
     renderSectionHeader={this._renderHeader}
     ItemSeparatorComponent={this._renderItemSeparator}
   />
  );
 }
}
```

The error occurs at the start of the section list, but i think the problem regards the data that i take from the props, because if i use static data the problem doesn't occurs.
Someone can help me?

Comment: any luck with this?  i have been stuck on this for 2 days.  code works on ios but android gives me the same error.